# NGINX rewrites with regular expression

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri @moved;
  location @moved {
  rewrite ^/categories/dogs-c-food/products/xyz-product$ /categories/dogs/food/products/xyz-product permanent;
  rewrite ^/categories/dogs-c-leash/products/xyz-product$ /categories/dogs/leash/products/xyz-product permanent;
  rewrite ^/categories/cats-c-litter-box/products/xyz-product$ /categories/cats/litter-box/products/xyz-product permanent;
}
```

want to use one line regex and replace `-c-` with a `/`

Comment: Isn't that exactly what this expression does? What's wrong ?

Comment: yes it works. want to make it dynamic

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect some addresses you want to rewrite and the expected results ?

Comment: Try something like the following `^/categories/(.*?)-c-(.*?)/?$ categories/$1/$2`

Comment: thanks HamZa, that is what i am looking for but its not working. still getting 404 and nothing in error log.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri @moved;

location @moved {
    rewrite ^/categories/(.+)-c-(.+)$ "/categories/$1/$2" permanent;
}
```

And be careful with the slashes, Since $URI always start with a slash (/), so after redirecting to the new 'moved' scenario it should be like the same.

Comment: thanks but i get this in error log-- failed: nothing to repeat in "^/categories/(+*)-c-(+*)$" at "+*)-c-(+*)$"

Comment: Sorry, there has been a typo in the rewrite line (i have updated it)... so please use it this way-- `rewrite ^/categories/(.+)-c-(.+)$ "/categories/$1/$2" permanent;`  -- it will work now.